# DotNet Core - Purpose of Solution Files

Tags: c#, .net-core

What's the purpose of using solution files for DotNet Core projects? I'm using a Mac, and I can use project-to-project reference to modularize and build shared libraries without solution files:

```
dotnet add reference ..\Library\Library.csproj
```

which adds the following to my current directory's .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Library\Library.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And now building my current directory's .csproj will build Library.csproj.

Comment: To link multiple projects...?

Comment: you can open multiple projects at the same time with solution files. otherwise you'd have to open them one by one

Comment: On a Mac, so there is no IDE to open solution files. You open directories using VS Code / Sublime / Atom / etc.

Comment: Imagine you have a web server project, and a dll project that contains your business logic, and then another dll project that contains your data classes.

Comment: Completely agree @john, and I can use project-to-project references to link them. I don't need a solution file to do that.

Comment: @AzizJaved have you tried Rider IDE? It should open `.sln` files from Visual Studio world.

Comment: @AzizJaved - you have answered you question - _I don't need a solution file to do that_. `.sln` file need for Visual Studio to open multiple projects with build configuration. If you not using Visual Studio - you don't need it.

Comment: Visual Studio solution files are just another level you can use to group projects and files that do not belong to projects. They also allow you to create virtual folders for projects, so they can be used to organize multi-project “solutions” (hence the name). Further, they allow you to specify build configuration combinations. But you are right: You don’t necessarily **need** them; they are an artifact of the old style project format. And I wouldn’t be surprised if they end up being changed/removed when everything is migrated to the new project format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solution file works as container for application's project/projects. It comes handy when you are working on your application out of IDE. Following are some of uses of solution file.

1. Open project or multiple projects in IDE just by opening solution file in IDE. e.g. If you open solution file in visual studio then all of projects which are part of solution will get opened in visual studio.
2. You can control build/deployment of projects (what to build and what not to) under solution using solution level configuration.
3. If you are using editor like VS Code then solution file facilitate to build all those project which are part of solution just by running "dotnet build" command. If projects were not part of solution then you need to build them individually.
4. When working out of IDE (like Visual Studio) and source control you can add all project files and solution to source control just by adding solution to source control. Same goes with check in or checkout.

These are some of advantages of solution file and there can be many more. However solution file is not must have thing and you can still live without it. Its just makes developer's life easy and improves productivity.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Pankaj. Response to your four points: 1) I'm using VS Code on a Mac, so doesn't really apply here. 2) Thought this was an anti-pattern, since it leads to monolith solutions and is better to have multiple solutions. Consequently is this even a valuable benefit? 3) VS Code will also do this for project-to-project references. 4) Using terminal, so doesn't apply.

Comment: @AzizJaved You asked for the purpose of solution files and were provided with them. You also replied with point #1 after already receiving a comment which informed you that there are IDEs available for Mac which do open .sln files appropriately. Your responses all seem to indicate that you don't really want to use them, and that's fine because no one is forcing you to do so.

Answer (score -2):

Solution files are only useful for VisualStudio today.
In general their purpose is to combine multiple C# projects under the "same hood" and centralise the managment of packages for all those projects.

This style has fallen out of favour as most projects today are not combination of multiple smaller ones.

In modern architecture you want one project in one repository.
The only reason to extract a functionality into a separate project is if more than 3 other projects do the same.
Even in this case you will prefer to create a package that will be reused by your projects instead of combining multiple projects in the same repo so you can use solution files.

In general, solution files are ancient tech that is going away.

Comment: I don't think this comment has a single point that's valid or right.  Every single comment is outright wrong. It even sounds like trolling.