# Azure DevOps pipeline 'dotnet build' can't find project

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I have a repository which has nothing on master, except the Readme and azure-pipelines.yml YAML. On the development branch (the branch I want to build and deploy and have CI on) there are three folders, MVC, Test, and Console, each containing a project (an MVC version of an ASP.NET Core MVC, .NET Core console, and Xunit test project). I want to run `dotnet restore` and build on the MVC project, but I get the error:

```
2019-02-08T15:09:20.9373945Z ##[section]Starting: CmdLine
2019-02-08T15:09:20.9468192Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-08T15:09:20.9468291Z Task         : Command Line
2019-02-08T15:09:20.9468353Z Description  : Run a command line script using cmd.exe on Windows and bash on macOS and Linux.
2019-02-08T15:09:20.9468441Z Version      : 2.146.1
2019-02-08T15:09:20.9468490Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-02-08T15:09:20.9468565Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
2019-02-08T15:09:20.9468629Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-08T15:09:22.4499876Z Generating script.
2019-02-08T15:09:22.5206191Z ##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\21484123-df40-47c7-9383-7f526daaa124.cmd""
2019-02-08T15:09:22.8173263Z MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
2019-02-08T15:09:22.8173430Z Switch: MVC
2019-02-08T15:09:23.1247189Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
2019-02-08T15:09:23.1308513Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2019-02-08T15:09:23.1308642Z
2019-02-08T15:09:23.1308714Z MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
2019-02-08T15:09:23.1308801Z Switch: MVC
2019-02-08T15:09:23.2993350Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
2019-02-08T15:09:23.3158684Z ##[section]Finishing: CmdLine
```

The YAML file in master is the following:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- dev
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

#- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
#  inputs:
#    version: '2.2.103' # replace this value with the version that you need for your project

steps:
- script: |
    dotnet restore MVC
    dotnet build MVC
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

Is there a way to access MVC for the `dotnet` commands?

Comment: if your yaml file exists in dev it should work just fine, the only caveat is that your solution file should be in the root of the repo (i think)

Comment: @4c74356b41, thanks so much! but when I make the build with azure it automatically puts the YAML into master. And what do you mean by solution file? Sorry for the dumb questions I'm having a very tough time getting CI set up

Comment: you can copy it to a dev branch, its just a file. solution file, you can google it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426982/dotnet-core-purpose-of-solution-files?rq=1

Comment: Add a `dir` command to print out where the current directory is and what it contains. Then the cause should be clear. Also use your own build agent machine instead of Microsoft's hosted ones so that you can troubleshoot on that box locally.